# Windows 10 Wallpaper - photo location

Tags: where-on-earth, new-zealand, lock-screens

I've upgraded my laptop to Win10, and I have this wallpaper on my screen:

[image: Archway Islands on Wharariki Beach]

[image: Archway Islands on Wharariki Beach]

I like this place and I wanted to know - where it exactly is?

Search in Internet gave me [this old post about windows wallpapers](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/01/24/desktop-background-location_n_4604287.html) and [similar question on Microsoft site](http://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_10-start/%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0/f0d9a69a-8234-4fca-8a51-15cef1ab7445) with no answer.

Comment: Just for the challenge add this to the question: ...and what was the running guy's name.

Comment: I'm sure it's a girl.

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Comment: Is it relevant for the question to have a New Zealand tag (the geo-location of the photo) while the OP didn't know the geo-location at all when they asked?

Comment: @SnackExchange I suggest to leave this question as is, as it was bad when it has been asked, and closed for 6 years. Even though I didn't know the exact location, I think this question can be useful for a person who searches something about New Zealand and beautiful places there

Comment: Whoi is the lady running?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Those are the *Archway Islands* on [Wharariki Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wharariki_Beach) in New Zealand:

[image: archway islands]

([Source](https://www.travelblog.org/Photos/419581) - no author specified)

Comment: Just curious, how did you find it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Google image search -> Quora question about the same picture

Comment: These are indeed archway islands on Wharariki Beach, West Coast New Zealand, and they are as amazing as you see them here, we live about 2hrs drive from there and visit quite regularly, the right side of the front island has a seal colony, and in the spring you can see the seal pups!